# Python loads data from Redshift to S3

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to load some Redshift query results to S3. So far I am using pandas_redshift but I got stuck:

```
import pandas_redshift as pr

pr.connect_to_redshift( dbname = 'dbname',
                    host = 'xxx.us-east-    1.redshift.amazonaws.com',
                    port = 5439,
                    user = 'xxx',
                    password = 'xxx')

pr.connect_to_s3(aws_access_key_id = 'xxx',
            aws_secret_access_key = 'xxx',
            bucket = 'dxxx',
            subdirectory = 'dir')
```

And here is the data that I want to dump to S3:

```
sql_statement = '''
select
provider,
provider_code 
from db1.table1
group by provider, provider_code;

'''
df = pr.redshift_to_pandas(sql_statement)
```

The df was created successfully but how to do the next step, which is to put this dataframe to S3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are looking at is very inefficient.

to do this the right way you will need a way to run sql on redshift - via e.g. python.

the following sql should be run

```
unload ('select provider,provider_code
         from db1.table1
           group by provider, provider_code;')   
to 's3://mybucket/myfolder/unload/' 
access_key_id '<access-key-id>'
secret_access_key '<secret-access-key>';
```

see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Unloading_tables.html) fore documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Scott mentions if your goal is to move data from redshift to S3, then the pandas_redshift package is not the right method. The package is meant to allow you to easily move data from redshift to a Pandas DataFrame on your local machine, or move data from a Pandas DataFrame on your local machine to redshift. It is worth noting that running the command you already have:

```
df = pr.redshift_to_pandas(sql_statement)
```

Pulls the data directly from redshift to your computer without involving S3 at all. However this command:

```
pr.pandas_to_redshift(df, 'schema.your_new_table_name')
```

Copies the DataFrame to a CSV in S3, then runs a query to copy CSV to redshift (This step requires that you ran pr.connect_to_s3 successfully). It does not perform any cleanup of the S3 bucket so a side effect of this is that the data will end up in the bucket you specify.